# Is there an easy way to add a secondary y-axis to a Plotly plot without the need of providing a second array?

Tags: python, plotly, interactive

I want to have two y-axes for the same time series, an axis with the absolute number as values, and an axis with the percentages as values. [Draft schematics of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6rWc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way of doing it without 2 traces. It does mean each trace can be switched on / off in legend so that hover gives interactivity.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = pd.date_range("14-feb-2022", freq="1H", periods=400)
y = np.sort(np.random.pareto(2, 400))[::-1]

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="abs"),
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y / y.max(),
            name="% max",
            yaxis="y2",
        ),
    ],
    layout={
        "yaxis2": {
            "side": "right",
            "tickformat": ",.0%",
        },
        "yaxis": {"overlaying": "y2"},
        "legend": {"orientation": "h", "xanchor": "center", "x": 0.5},
    },
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is the closest to what I have imagined.